# applicationWillEnterForeground & UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, appdelegate

I have an issue with my obj-c iOS app.

I have a main view in it which is called to appear - when the app is reentering the foreground from the background - via `applicationWillEnterForeground`.
The thing is that when I use `UIActivityViewController` to open some content in another app (fx. *Messages*) this extern app opens on the top of my own and therefore, when I close the extern one, my own is not still in the foreground and `applicationWillEnterForeground` is not called. This causes a crash in my app.

I am looking for a possible alternative for `applicationWillEnterForeground` that tells the `AppDelegate` if the app is "in background" of another app via `UIActivityViewController`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can use these delegate methods -

`- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application;
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application;`

Comment: That did not change anything.